# fetch vs. [] when working with hashes?

Tags: ruby

From Ruby Koans `about_hashes.rb`:

Why might you want to use `#fetch` instead of `#[]` when accessing hash keys?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

By default, using `#[]` will retrieve the hash value if it exists, and return nil if it doesn't exist *.

Using `#fetch` gives you a few options (see the docs on [#fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch)):

- `fetch(key_name)`: get the value if the key exists, raise a `KeyError` if it doesn't
- `fetch(key_name, default_value)`: get the value if the key exists, return `default_value` otherwise
- `fetch(key_name) { |key| "default" }`: get the value if the key exists, otherwise run the supplied block and return the value.

Each one should be used as the situation requires, but `#fetch` is very feature-rich and can handle many cases depending on how it's used. For that reason I tend to prefer it over accessing keys with `#[]`.

* As Marc-André Lafortune said, accessing a key with `#[]` will call `#default_proc` if it exists, or else return `#default`, which defaults to `nil`. See [the doc entry for `::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)  for more information.

Comment: Good answer, except it is not technically correct. `#[]` when the key does not exist will call `#default_proc` if any or else return `#default`. By default, `#default` returns `nil`.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune thanks, I learnt something new! Updated answer.

Comment: Point of clarification, `key` in the last example may not be the best name for what is yielded to the block. In the case `key_name` is found, fetch will yield the `value` at `key_name` and the `key` if not.

Comment: However, you can do this: `arr = [1,2,3]` `arr[1..-2] #=> [1,2]`  
But not this:
    `arr.fetch(1..-2) #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Range into Integer`

Similarly you can mutate an array with `Hash#[]`

    `arr[1] = "A"`
    `arr #=> ["A",2,3]`

But not with fetch:

    `arr.fetch(1) = "A" #=> unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input`

Answer (score 32):

With `[]`, the creator of the hash controls what happens when a key does not exist, with `fetch` you do.

Answer (score 7):

`fetch` by default raises an error if the key is not found. You can supply a default value instead.

```
h = {}

h.fetch(:foo) # no default value, raises error
# => # ~> -:3:in `fetch': key not found: :foo (KeyError)

h.fetch(:bar, 10) # default value, returns default value
# => 10
```

Comment: `h[:foo]` is the same as `h.fetch(:foo, nil)`.

Comment: @LBg: it behaves the same, yes

Comment: @LBg: No, it isn't. It is the same as `begin h.fetch(:foo); rescue KeyError; if h.default_proc then h.default_proc.() else h.default end end`.