# Why isn't an exception thrown when the hash value doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby

I'm learning the Ruby language and while compiling a simple print operation I saw one strange thing. The code is given below :

```
z = { 'mike' => 75, 'bill' => 18, 'alice' => 32 }

print z['bill'], " ", z['joe'], "  "\n"
```

Here I get the output as `18`; even though there is no value available for `joe` it is not throwing any error.

Why is that so? In other languages like `c#` it will throw an exception!

Is it because I'm compiling it using an online compiler?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception because that's not how Ruby handles it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When an hash key is not found in an `Hash`, the method `[]` will, by default, return `nil`. Therefore in the case of `z['joe']` it will result in `nil`, which when printed results in an empty string.

On the other hand, when you initialize the hash, you can define a block of code which will be run when the key does not exist in the hash. For example:

```
z = Hash.new do |hash, key|
  raise("Key #{ key } is not valid")
end
```

As an alternative you can also use [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) and let it fail with `KeyError`, or specify either a default value or a block of code to be executed (like in `new`) when the key does not exits.

Comment: but it should be error know because there is no one called joe !

Comment: @Jefffrey You may want to take a look at [`Hash#fetch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Comment: "When an hash key is not found in an `Hash`, the method `[]` will return `nil`." – Actually, when a `Hash` key is not found, that hash's `default_proc` is executed, unless it is `nil`, in which case that hash's `default` is returned, which happens to default to `nil`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Right. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: A great explanation of the use of `fetch` over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16569515/293280

Answer (score 5):

This is clearly documented in the documentation for the method [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> ## `hsh[key]` → `value`
>
> Element Reference—Retrieves the *value* object corresponding to the *key* object. If not found, returns the default value (see [`Hash::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-c-new) for details).
>
> ```
> h = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
> h["a"]   #=> 100
> h["c"]   #=> nil
> ```

The last line in the code sample even shows your *exact* situation.

So, why doesn't it `raise` an `Exception`? Well, because accessing a non-existing key in a dictionary is simply not an exceptional situation!

Plus, it's trivial to initialize a `Hash` with a `default_proc` that `raise`s a `KeyError`:

```
z = { 'mike' => 75, 'bill' => 18, 'alice' => 32 }
z.default_proc = -> (h, k) { raise KeyError, "#{k} not found!" }

z['joe']
# KeyError: joe not found!
```

Now, if there *wasn't* a way to specify a default value, and instead you would always get an exception, it would be much harder to implement it the other way around.